# How to call the model function every one hour using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to call the function model function in every one hour using Codeigniter.

My model function:

```
$to = "xx@exmple.com";
$subject = "Test";
$message = "Hello.";
$from = "yy@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . "admin@gmail.com";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Here I need to call the mail function every one hour. How can I do this?

Comment: How about using a cron job?

Comment: I dont'  about cron.

Comment: Are you on Windows or a *NIX operating system?

Comment: Start by reading up on [Running Codeigniter via the CLI](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/general/cli.html) then look up cron https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Comment: window.setInterval(function(){
  load_data();
}, 5000);  Here this load_data() function call when the page is not open ?

Comment: @kidA Let's not do anything too crazy here. Personally, I love re-inventing the wheel

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is use cron jobs instead.
setting cron job from server is quite easy,
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs

Comment: How to create a cron job. Please help me.

Comment: actually for cron jobs you need to add a function in controller which fetch data from model – and this function should be accessible from url – mean no validation etc should exist there, after that you have to make some settings in server from cpanel, which means in server a option exist to run that url timely.

Comment: you have access to cpanel?